# How does SQL load images?

Tags: sql-server, image, loading

How does SQL server load images?  For example, say I have a table with 11,000 rows and each row has an image.  Some images in the table appear multiple times.  Currently, I think depending on the network traffic, it can take anywhere from 1 minute up to 10 minutes to load the entire table because all 11,000 images are downloaded even though there might only be 500 unique images.

Because the same image can be loaded 30-50 times, I'm wondering if I created a separate table that stored just an Image_ID and the actual Image and then changed the Image field from the 1st table to just an Image_ID field if that would speed up loading. My thought process is to load a table of all the unique images into memory (that way only ~500 unique images need loaded) and then just use a table to reference the loaded images.  This way only 500 images need to be loaded instead of 11,000.  Is this possible?

I've tried Googling to see if I could find how SQL loads images but I can't find much information on how much time it takes SQL to query images.  If anyone has any links or examples that would be helpful, thank you!

[Example of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMZGj.jpg)

Comment: Are the images stored on disk as FileSystem tables or are they in a regular table as a VARBINARY field?

Comment: The images are currently stored in a regular table as an "image" datatype which I know is deprecated and it should probably be varbinary(max).

Comment: You're right to think that each time you transfer a record over the wire it is transferred in it's entirety. SQL Server doesn't know that just because you have duplicated records it should do anything different than normal. If you want to load them faster you'll need to do something creative on your end. I don't think there is a SQL Server setting to handle this for you.